# Java on OpenWrt/DD-WRT

Tags: java, openwrt

I have an existing solution written in Java which I would love to run on [OpenWrt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenWrt) routers. Will OpenWrt even run Java without installing a lot of dependencies? Anyone ever tried this?

Comment: did you get it done? If yes, what version of java is running on your OpenWRT?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not look into it much further.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've never done it, but it is definitively possible. You won't be able to run the *full* Java VM, only specialized versions of it ([JamVM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jamvm/), [PhoneME](https://phoneme.dev.java.net/), SableVM). Also please be aware that running a Java VM is fairly a lot overhead for this kind of machine.

I won't get much in detail because others have already done it. Check out these links.

- http://wiki.openembedded.net/index.php/Java
- http://wolfpaulus.com/journal/embedded/fonera3
- http://wolfpaulus.com/talks/openwrt.pdf
- http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Mobileandembedded/PhoneMEAdvancedGSGOpenWRT
- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/tech/index-jsp-139293.html

---

**EDIT**: SableVM is unmaintained.

**EDIT**: As [Amigable Clark Kant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/193892) mentioned, you could [compile your Java code to native](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8757) by using the [GNU Compiler for Java](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/).

Answer (score 2):

Since your goal is to get the existing solution running on the router, and not explicitly get a JVM running on the router, I would suggest going the other way:

compile the Java code to native! This also has the potential to be just as fast a C code.

There is an [article in Linux journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8757) about this.

If not your cup of tea, [JAMVM](http://jamvm.sourceforge.net/) seems a better fit for a small system such as OpenWRT.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this on a Asus WL-HDD some time ago with [SableVM](http://www.sablevm.org/). The WL-HDD [can run Debian](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianWRT) and connect some memory/hdd through USB. But performance was really bad.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Embeded JRE these days. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/overview/index.html

It also exists for ARM and not only for Intel architecture platforms.

Answer (score 1):

In the OpenWrt version 21.02, you can [install Docker directly](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/virtualization/docker_host), so you can also try to run a Java app in a Docker container.
You can also try Podman instead of the Docker.

But still the MIPS router probably won't be supported, only ARM.
Try the [eclipse-temurin](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-temurin) images because they have a wide support of architectures. For example they have a build of OpenJDK 17 TLS for the arm v7.
Their image is based on Ubuntu 22.04 and uses glibc inside of a container.

Answer (score 1):

The Alpine Linux is also based on musl library so you may try to download the OpenJDK from their repository.
Here is a sample how to install OpenJDK 8 to Turris Omnia router
https://gist.github.com/stokito/7dd425da5a12abce8b39dda1bd1106d7

The Zulu OpenJDK have [Alpine builds for x86_64 and armv8 64](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?os=alpine-linux)

The Eclipse Temurin (AdoptOpenJDK) [doesn't have yet Alpine builds](https://github.com/adoptium/containers/issues/141)